# Hide and show menu child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working with a piece of jquery that hides and shows several divs when a menu item is clicked.

However at the moment you if you were to click on the same menu item the newly opened div remains open instead of closing as desired. I would also like to achieve a hide div function when the div class 'submit' is click.

Any advice would be great

https://jsfiddle.net/a9ykpdwz/

Jquery

```
$("#one, #two, #three").hide();

$(".one, .two, .three").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#" + $(this).attr("class")).fadeIn(1000).siblings('#one, #two, #three').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="nav">

<a href="#" class="one">WORK</a>
<a href="#" class="two">ABOUT</a>
<a href="#" class="three">CONTACT</a>
</div>

<div id="one">
<ul>
<li>xx</li> 
<li>Spaces</li>
<li>Form</li>
<li>Mind and Body</li> 
<li>Moving Image</li> 
<li>White Trails</li> 
<li>Foreign Views</li>
<ul>
<div class="submit"> close </div>
</div>

<div id="two">Text</div>
<div id="three">Text</div>
```

Comment: @AliGajani if you click one of them menu items the div shows, but click the same menu item again and nothing happens

Comment: Do you want to toggle them on and off?

Comment: yes that would be ideal @AliGajani

Answer (score 0):

Use `fadeToggle()` instead of `fadeIn()`. I *assume* you mean you want all three divs hidden on `submit`, which works below.

```js
$("#one, #two, #three").hide();

$(".one, .two, .three").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $("#" + this.className).fadeToggle(1000).siblings('#one, #two, #three').fadeOut(1000);
});

$('.submit').click(function(e) {
  $('#one, #two, #three').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">

  <a href="#" class="one">WORK</a>
  <a href="#" class="two">ABOUT</a>
  <a href="#" class="three">CONTACT</a>
</div>

<div id="one">
  <ul>
    <li>xx</li>
    <li>Spaces</li>
    <li>Form</li>
    <li>Mind and Body</li>
    <li>Moving Image</li>
    <li>White Trails</li>
    <li>Foreign Views</li>
  </ul>    <!-- corrected a missing / here -->
  <div class="submit">close</div>
</div>

<div id="two">Text</div>
<div id="three">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not creating the event to the `.close` element
2. If you want to see the new element and hide the previous showed, you need to set as display none, without transition because the elements are stacked, in other case you need to change the elements as absolutes.

fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/a9ykpdwz/2/